# sumar valores de una columna con valores dinamicos de una base de datos

Tags: express, mongoose

estoy con un problema el cual no le encuentro una solucion. Ando practicando con expressjs y mongoose haciendo un crud. Tengo una lista de registros y cada registro tiene una columna con "Gastos" , alli tienen un valor numerico en cada fila, quisiera sumar esto pero no sabria como intente con helpers de handlebars y me da muchos problemas, consultas en mongoose se me hace muy complejo y necesito una ayuda para continuar... Tengo lo siguiente:

1- index.js

```
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const products = await Products.find({}).lean();
  res.render("index", { products });
});
```

2-index.hbs (utilizo handlebars )

```
{{#each products}}
        <tr>
            <td class="align-middle">{{ @index }}</td>
            <td class="align-middle">{{date}}</td>
            <td class="align-middle">{{establecimiento}}</td>
            <td class="align-middle"></td>
            <td class="align-middle">{{ cost}}</td> // quiero sumar toda esta columna
            <td class="d-flex">
                <a href="edit/{{_id}}" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="bi bi-pencil"></i></a>
                <form class="p-2" action="/item/delete/{{_id}}?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit"><i class="bi bi-trash-fill"></i></button>
                </form>
            </td>
            

        </tr>
        {{/each}}
        <table class="table">
        <td colspan="1" class="table-active "> TOTAL </td>
        <td class="table-active " colspan="2">{{aqui va el total de la suma de costos}}</td>
        </thead>
```

/// PRIMER UPDATE

Estuve haciendo algunas pruebas con el siguiente codigo

```
router.get("/request", (req, res) => {
  const query = Products.find().select('cost -_id');
  query.exec(function (err, po){
    if(err) return next(err);
    po.reduce(function(accumulator, item){
      const toNumber = parseFloat(item.cost);
      return console.log(accumulator + item.cost);
    },0);
    
  })
  
});
```

mi modelo es el siguiente

```
const ProductSchema = new Schema ({
    number: {type: Number, },
    date: {type: String, },
    establecimiento: {type: String, required:true},
    cost: {type: Number, required:true}
});
```

Quiero sumar cost. Con las pruebas que estuve haciendo, el console.log me arroja el primer valor, pero los demas como NaN

411
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN

Sin embargo con .reduce() se deberia sumar... no entiendo bien.

/// SEGUNDO UPDATE

Logre que me devuelva la suma, pude colocarlo en index.hbs, me falta solo ponerlo en search.hbs y que suma la cantidad de filas encontradas.

```
router.get("/request", (req, res) => {
  const query = Products.find().select('cost -_id');
  const reducer = (prev, current) => prev+current;
  query.exec(function(err, docs){
    docs = docs.map(function(doc) {return doc.cost;});
    if(err){
      res.json(err)
    } else {
     console.log(docs.reduce(reducer))
    }
  })
});
```

/// Tercer update

Asi es como funciona mi search.

```
router.get("/search", function (req, res) {
  var noMatch = null;
  function escapeRegex(text) {
    return text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
  }
  if (req.query.search) {
    const regex = new RegExp(escapeRegex(req.query.search), "gi");

    Products.find({ establecimiento: regex }, function (err, finding) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        if (finding.length < 1) {
          noMatch = "No results match that query, please try again.";
        }

        res.render("search", { productos: finding, noMatch: noMatch });
      }
    }).lean();
  } else {
    Products.find({}, function (err, finding) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        res.render("search", { productos: finding, noMatch: noMatch });
      }
    }).lean();
  }
});
```

Desde ya muchisimas gracias

Answer (score 0):

reduce deberia funcionar para lo que necesitas.

tu planteamiento es correcto al usar 'parseFloat()', pero no usas esa variable al trabajar con los datos:

```js
po.reduce(function(accumulator, item){
   const toNumber = parseFloat(item.cost);
   return console.log(accumulator + item.cost);
},0);
```

deberias simplemente utilizar la variable en la operacion para que el bucle funcione:

```js
po.reduce(function(accumulator, item){
  const toNumber = parseFloat(item.cost);
  console.log(accumulator + toNumber);
  return accumulator + toNumber;
},0);
```

espero esto te ayude, saludos.

*****actualizacion*****

he realizado esta prueba, que simula tu coleccion de objetos y funciona correctamente:

```js
var elementos = [
  {
    number: 0,
    date: 'fecha',
    establecimiento: 'establecimiento',
    cost: 1
  },
  {
    number: 1,
    date: 'fecha',
    establecimiento: 'establecimiento',
    cost: 3
  },
  {
    number: 2,
    date: 'fecha',
    establecimiento: 'establecimiento',
    cost: 1
  },
  {
    number: 3,
    date: 'fecha',
    establecimiento: 'establecimiento',
    cost: 6
  },
  {
    number: 4,
    date: 'fecha',
    establecimiento: 'establecimiento',
    cost: 20
  },
  {
    number: 5,
    date: 'fecha',
    establecimiento: 'establecimiento',
    cost: 54
  }
]

var resultado = elementos.reduce(function(accumulator, item){
  const toNumber = parseFloat(item.cost);
  return accumulator + toNumber;
},0);

console.log(resultado); // 85
```

//****actualizacion 2****//

si lo he entendido bien, simplemente necesitas agregar un codigo similar al que utilizas en el metodo "/request":

```js
Products.find({}, function (err, finding) {
      if (err) {
        res.json(err)
      } else {
        const reducer = (prev, current) => prev+current;
        var costeTotal = finding.map(function(doc) {return doc.cost;}).reduce(reducer); //puedes encadenar los 2 metodos de este modo en vez de hacerlos por separado.
        var totalFilas = finding.length; //aqui te dara el total de elementos en el array de objetos, es decir, la cantidad de filas que ha encontrado.
        res.render("search", { 
          productos: finding,
          noMatch: noMatch,
          costeTotal: costeTotal,
          totalFilas: totalFilas
        });
      }
    }).lean();
```

espero que esto te ayude, cualquier cosa comenta y buscamos otra solucion.

Comment: Logre hacerlo funcionar, expressjs pinta los resultados de la suma de los datos del modelo de mongoose, el tema ahora es ponerlo en el search. Estoy averiguando como hacerlo..

Comment: Intentar poner la funcion del segundo update, solo trae problemas.. intente formatearla de alguna manera , mi tema es buscar algo parecido al query.exec(function......

Comment: no veo como funciona tu search, si me incluyes algo se ese codigo puedo ver que necesitas para encontrar una solucion. y si me indicas por donde te falla o que problemas te da la funcion que te propongo, lo miramos a ver que cambios podemos hacer para que se adapte a lo que necesitas

Comment: Ahi edite la publicacion y agregue un update que contiene el codigo del search!. Desde ya, muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: se ve bien, lo que necesitas es que el metodo search te devuelva en la res la cantidad de filas y la suma de los costes, es asi??

Comment: Si, correcto!  Eso estuve intentando

Comment: ok, edito la respuesta a ver si te sirve.